# Find minimum in groups in a large MySQL value (using existing index) fast

Tags: mysql, join, database-performance

I've got a table with a few million data entries.
I'm trying to find minimum and maximum per group for a single item quickly.

The structure is like this

- "GROUPC" VarChar 10
- "Item" Integer
- "LogDT" Datetime
- many other fields.

There's a index on "GROUPC"/"LogDT" and there are less than 10 groups.

When I request a single GROUPC/Item minimum, I get a quick  response in 100ms

Example: Item 59

```
 select GROUPC, min(LogDT) from TABLE as T where T.Item=59 and t.GROUPC='GR1'
```

I need the minimum for all groups.

```
select GROUPC, min(LogDT) from TABLE as T where T.Item=59 group by t.GROUPC
```

This works, but takes 12 seconds, allthough there are only currently 3 groups.

Getting a list of groups takes only 15ms

```
select distinct GROUPC from TABLE
```

Any ideas how I can combine these two requests into something speedy?

Comment: Noted. I was using "GROUP" as a substitute for the real name of the field in my code, to make my question easier to understand. Will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an index on the `GROUP` and the `LogDT` columns, and this is good, so I believe that this query will be quite fast:

```
SELECT GROUP, MIN(LOGDT) FROM TABLE AS t GROUP BY t.GROUP
```

but since you are filtering by Item=59, and you don't have an index on the Item column, your query will be slow:

```
SELECT GROUP, MIN(LogDT) FROM TABLE as T WHERE T.Item=59 GROUP BY t.GROUP
```

I suspect that your first query is fast because group GR1 contains fewer items than other groups:

```
SELECT GROUP, MIN(LogDT) FROM TABLE as T WHERE T.Item=59 AND t.GROUP='GR1'
```

but if you try to filter by other groups (eg. GR2, GR3, ...) you might get slower performances.

You could give this code a try but I don't think it will make an improvement:

```
SELECT GROUP, MIN(LogDT) FROM TABLE as T
WHERE T.Item=59 AND t.GROUP IN (SELECT DISTINCT GROUP FROM TABLE)
GROUP BY t.GROUP
```

The only way to improve your performances is to add an index on the `Item` column.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I might have to use the extra index.

Comment: used the suggestion for the extra index after all